# Mobile app vulnerability scanner for Android and iOS

Tags: mobile, android, ios, vulnerability-scanners

I want to choose the best vulnerability scanner for mobile applications (Andorid & iOS) to secure our mobile apps.
What tools and products do you suggest? I had not any experience with any of them, so I don't know which one is better.

Comment: Keep in mind that secure applications are part of design. An insecure application may not be properly detected by a vulnerability scanner, but such scanners can nevertheless be a helpful tool.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about product recommendations are usually considered off-topic for Stack Exchange. There is a Software Recommendations SE site, but they will require that you list more specific requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Mobile Applications unlike web applications, are native apps which are installed on to the mobile operating system using a package. A mobile app is likely to follow a server client approach where the native app speaks to a server [eg: Facebook, Ebay]

Automated source code audit is possible on both the server side code and the client side code. Almost all the commercial scanners like IBM Appscan, HP Fortify and Checkmarx has modules which support such analysis for android native app code and the server side JAVA code and objective C.

However dynamic scanning of mobile applications is a lot more tricky. It will be almost impossible for a scanner to crawl though the API methods available. [Manual testing](https://secvibe.com/android-appsec-27855dca8531#.fskla3eca) would yield much more accurate results.